# Any good ideas for Visual Studio 2010 related projects for an internship?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I have an internship coming up in February where I will work with Visual Studio ALM (TS) 2010. My company tutor let me be free in choosing what I would like to work on with Visual Studio ALM...it kind of has to be something new, interesting and which will have a benefit for the company.

I'm not very familiar with VS ALM 2010 or Team Foundation Server etc. so I would like to know if anybody here has experience with this so they could give me some starting ideas for what is needed for VSTS, or what could be developed for VSTS. The programming language will be C# and I will be programming in VS 2008/2010.

***TL;DR:***

I will be programming in C#, using VS 2008/2010. Does anybody have any good ideas of what add-ons I could develop for VSTS ALM 2010? Does anybody have ideas of what could be integrated into/implemented alongside VSTS ALM 2010 to make it better or just give a better added value to the company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to go to your company and ask people who use VS what they feel would be of some benefit. Being able to tailor your responses to an actual need will give you a lot of bonus points :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you ask your "company tutor" for a list of people he or she feels are appropriate for you to ask for a five minute meeting with, who you could then introduce yourself to by e-mail, later ask for a meeting with ... or ask the company tutor to arrange such meetings for you ... and, in those meetings, ask some open-ended questions about what you could do to be useful.

This recommendation is based on the idea that your "company tutor" knows who can, and might, have their work interrupted, or their schedules impinged upon ... and who you should not approach because of deadlines pending, or whatever.

If the company has a company-wide forum (private forum), you might ask your tutor to let you post a message of introduction in which you express who you are, what your goals are, ask for responses; I'd say be sure and have the tutor sign off on your message before posting it if you have your own account : there are company "norms" and culture you will almost certainly not know about.

Please consider this "advice" with some caution : after all, if this is a company with ten divisions, and one-hundred programmers working on twenty projects, that's a whole different story than a small company where you might actually have the chance to meet, even know everyone, face-to-face.

Good luck !